# getting the total of amount of money of each user between two dates even if no record is found

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I am trying to get the total amount of money which the user spent between a certain period. The code that I have come up with can successfully get the result but I also want to show the users who didn't spend any money on that certain period.

The code I have come up with:

```
select guest_id,
    sum(spent)
from shopping_t  
left join 
(
    SELECT ADDDATE( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH, INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY) AS days
    FROM (
        SELECT a.a
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
    ) a
    JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) r1
    WHERE 
    @i < DATEDIFF(NOW(), NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
) as target
on shopping_date = target.days 
where shopping_date = target.days
group by guest_id
```

The code above gives me this result:

```
id  spent
0   220000
2   10000
```

My desired output is:

```
id  spent
0   220000
1   0 <----- I also want to display users who didn't suspend anything on that period
2   10000
```

guest_t table:

```
id  name    address     telphone    
0   George  Summerwind  042968084       
1   Lisa    Laplace     042968084       
2   Anne    Windhill    042968084       
3   Mike    Fairview    042168084
```

shopping_t table:

```
id  spent   date
0   150000  2016-03-02
0   50000   2016-01-03
0   20000   2016-02-16
1   1500    2014-01-02
1   3400    2014-01-03
2   9000    2016-01-02
2   1000    2016-01-03
```

I have tried crossing date list query and guest_t and left join to shopping_t but I can't figure out what is wrong: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57f9d/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to see every single user, table `guest_t` should be the main table. You can then `LEFT JOIN` shopping_t to it for existing shopping records.

This query use the period from 01-01-2016 to 01-04-2016. It seems to be what has been used for your desired output. I remove the calendar query because it does not seem required in your desired output.

#### Query:

```
SELECT gt.name, gt.id, coalesce(sum(st.money), 0) 
FROM guest_t AS gt
LEFT JOIN shopping_t AS st
    ON gt.id = st.guest_id
        AND st.shopping_date >= '2016-01-01' 
        AND st.shopping_date < '2016-04-01'
GROUP By gt.id, gt.name;
```

Coalesce replace `NULL` by `0`.

Output is similar to your desired output:

```
   name | id | coalesce(sum(st.money), 0) 
 george |  0 |                     220000 
   Lisa |  1 |                          0 
   Anne |  2 |                      10000 
   Mike |  3 |                          0
```

If you want data for the past 3 months starting NOW(), the calendar subquery is not needed. You only need to check the boundaries (NOW and NOW - 3 months) in the ON clause:

```
SELECT gt.name, gt.id, coalesce(sum(st.money), 0) 
FROM guest_t AS gt
LEFT JOIN shopping_t AS st
    ON gt.id = st.guest_id
        AND st.shopping_date >= (CURDATE () - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
        AND st.shopping_date < CURDATE ()
GROUP By gt.id, gt.name;
```

This query gives the same output.

Both query are in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a327d/12).

Your query with dates in the `WHERE` clause didn't work because a `LEFT JOIN` returns `NULL` for rows with no match in the shopping table. `NULL` cannot be compared to the dates and the result of the condition is false.  Therefore the whole row (guest+shooping) is discarded by the `WHERE` clause:

```
| id |   name |       city | address |       tel | point | etc | guest_id |  money |              shopping_date 
|  0 | george | Summerwind |         | 042968084 |  -100 |     |        0 | 150000 |    March, 02 2016 00:00:00 
|  0 | george | Summerwind |         | 042968084 |  -100 |     |        0 |  50000 |  January, 03 2016 00:00:00 
|  0 | george | Summerwind |         | 042968084 |  -100 |     |        0 |  20000 | February, 16 2016 00:00:00 
|  2 |   Anne |   Windhill |         | 042968084 |  -100 |     |        2 |   9000 |  January, 02 2016 00:00:00 
|  2 |   Anne |   Windhill |         | 042968084 |  -100 |     |        2 |   1000 |  January, 03 2016 00:00:00 
|  1 |   Lisa |    Laplace |         | 042968084 |     0 |     |   (null) | (null) |                     (null) 
|  3 |   Mike |   Fairview |         | 042168084 |     0 |     |   (null) | (null) |                     (null)
```

From this output, the last 2 row are discarded.

When the date condition is move to the `ON` clause, `shopping_t` is checked before the `LEFT JOIN`. If the condition is not true, they are not used in the `JOIN` and replaced by `NULL`. However because a `LEFT JOIN` `guest_t` data stay in place whether `shopping_t` returns nothing (`NULL`).

---

If you want to see each days whether there is data or not, you have to CROSS JOIN the calendar subquery with guest_t and then use a LEFT JOIN:

```
select guest_id, t.days
    coalesce(sum(money), 0)
from (
    SELECT ADDDATE...
) as t
CROSS JOIN guest_t gt
left join shopping_t  
    on gt.id = st.guest_id
        AND shopping_date = t.days 
group by guest_id, t.days;
```

I remove the final WHERE clause with is similar to ON clause.

Comment: thank you. it solved my problem .i made an exact similar query yesterday except the date condition is inside the where clause . can you explain why it didnt work?

Comment: I have added an explaination